# undertow subsystem configuration in keycloak for http listener

Tags: reverse-proxy, keycloak, undertow

Hello every one I am trying to configure keycloak and while skimming around the docs I have come across this config for undertow subsystem in wildfly (upon which keycloak runs) and verified it in my standalone.xml file

```
<server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
.....
.....

 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Now what I want to know is why the `http-listener` has a `redirect-socket` set to "https" as this listener is supposed to be listening for http requests made to the keycloak server? right? and we do have a separate `https-listener`. Also in a case of reverse proxy sitting in front of keycloak all requests made to keycloak via the proxy using http shall also end up on the `http listener` right? so why is http-listener redirecting request to a https socket binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What at first seems unreasonable has a very simple explanation: Keycloak should communicate with Users and Client over https. So, if a users attempts to start a session over http, he immediately redirected to https.
On the other hand, if a user already started a session over https, there is no need to redirect him further.